# Slow Gmail attachment download over HTTPS

Tags: gmail, https, latency, connection

It only affects Gmail. I have tested other HTTP, FTP and HTTPS websites and downloading is fine, at the exact same time the problem is affecting a Gmail attachment download.

The symptoms include both:

- High waiting time, before the download starts (on the order of 30 seconds); AND
- Very slow download transfer speeds (on the order of 1kbps)

It's a very strange problem, and I didn't find any recent issues relating to Google Australia. The account works fine at another site with a different ISP, so it's either a computer configuration or ISP - I lean to the latter.

Comment: I have the answer, I just need to wait 7 hours before I can though... not enough reputation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this can be fixed by disabling HTTPS for downloading attachments. Note, that this decreases security of the transfer of course, but it does restore normal download experience for attachments.

Instructions:

1. Open your Gmail account in web browser
2. Go to settings for your account (cog on the right > Settings)
3. In the general tab, find Browser connection
4. Set to Don't always user https
5. Scroll down, and click Save Changes

Note: There are two radio options, none of mine were selected.